# Model binding from input form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm working with Laravel and it seems in examples that they decide to implement validation inside controller, and I don't like it at all. What I want to ask is if there is some kind of `bind` method that can bind posted input fields to object that I created so that I can make sure my controllers are not messy.

I will try to explain what I want in code, I think it will be much clearer.

## What I have

```
public function postRegister() {
    $validation = Validator::make(Input::all(), array(
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required|min:6',
                'name' => 'required|alpha',
                'gender' => 'required|in:male,female'
    ));

    if ($validation->fails()) {
        Input::flashExcept('password');
        return Redirect::to('register')->withErrors($validation)->withInput();
    }

    // Register user...
}
```

## What I want to have

```
class UserRegisterDto {
    public $email;
    public $password;
    public $name;
    public $gender;

    protected $errors;

    public function isValid() {
        // Validate it here, set errors if there are some
        return $validator->isValid();
    }

    public function getErrors() {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}

public function postRegister() {
    $user = Input::bind('UserRegisterDto'); // This is made-up function, I wonder if something like this exists

    if ($user->isValid()) {
        // Register user...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ardent can help you to keep the controllers clean: https://github.com/laravelbook/ardent

"Ardent models use Laravel's built-in Validator class. Defining validation rules for a model is simple and is typically done in your model class as a static variable"

Comment: Hm, looks good however I'm confused about `save` function. What if (and in my case it's true) I'm using custom repository to save it since I'm not using MySql but Cassandra?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I use it with MySQL.